# Switch Card Layout in Java

Tags: java, swing, cardlayout

Here's how to change card layouts from a menu item. I asked how to do it earlier but no luck.  I have figured out the answer so here's what it does; 1. Builds your main frame when running the java file.  Then in the menu bar it allows you to switch JPanels (For this example welcome is a different public class inside of a package.) 2. Now you can build as many public classes as you want and still be able to go to that JPanel.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ArmyQuestions {

    CardLayout cards;
    JPanel cardPanel;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

         //Use the event dispatch thread for Swing components
         EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
         {

            @Override
             public void run()
             {

                 new ArmyQuestions();         
             }
         });

    }

    public ArmyQuestions()
    { 

        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();

        //make sure the program exits when the frame closes
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setTitle("Army Questions");
        mainFrame.setSize(797,510);

        //This will center the JFrame in the middle of the screen
        mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mainFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //Adds a menu bar
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        mainFrame.getContentPane().add(menuBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        //Adds a menu option
        JMenu mnFile = new JMenu("File");
        menuBar.add(mnFile);

        //Adds an item to the menu option
        JMenuItem mntmNew = new JMenuItem("New");
        mnFile.add(mntmNew);
        mntmNew.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
            {
                cards.show(cardPanel, "Welcome");
            }
        });

        //Adds cardpanel to getContentPane           
        cards = new CardLayout();
        cardPanel = new JPanel();
        cardPanel.setLayout(cards);
        mainFrame.getContentPane().add(cardPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //Adds a JPanel to your cardpanel 
        Welcome welcome = new Welcome();
        cardPanel.add(welcome, "Welcome");

        mainFrame.setVisible(true);


    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit down your code, removing any code that is not relevant to the question. Also, what is the _exact_ problem(s) you are having?

Comment: I have answered my own question and posted the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Two things I see going on.

1. You have `SuggestedQuesion_2` declared globally then you create a whole new one in you method. `JPanel SuggestedQuestion_2 = new JPanel();`
2. I see a `CardLayout` for your `Welcome` - `Welcome.setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));`, but not for you `SuggestedQuestion_2`. Yet you're trying to access `SuggestedQuestions`'s `CardLayout`

You should learn how to post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) So it is easier for us to see the problem. Also, in trying to recreate the problem into a smaller, runnable version you sometimes figure out the solution yourself.

And please follow Java naming convention using lowercase letters first letter of reference variable

Comment: I would recommend learning to hand write the swing programs. You will learn alot of things that will help you later on when creating with a GUI builder tool. See the [Swing tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Comment: I'm not used to using the GUI Builder so its hard for me to try and solve your problem